# SUPEE 7405: Frontend Cart Delete Action (Doesn't Work)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, php, supee-7405

After SUPEE 7405 installation, when using AJAX product delete action, it throws an error "Cannot remove the item." This message is due to added FORM-KEY validation into `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php`

**Now, the question is:** How to fix this issue? I've received comments saying I need to add a FORM-KEY to `.phtml` file responsible in ajax. But I DO NOT know which code to insert or file exactly I need to edit.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

I have it working by using the following as my deleteURL:

```
echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/delete', array('id' => $item->getId()))
    . "form_key/" . Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey();
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

Ok let me clarify this a bit.

With patch 7405, the form_key is added directly to the `getDeleteUrl` function of the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` block.

Thus when you inspect your delete link the href attribute should look like this:

`http://yourstore.com/checkout/cart/delete/id/<product_id>/form_key/<the_form_key>/uenc/<encoded_part>/`

**There is no need to add the form key to the template** as it's directly added to the URL.

If your delete URL does not have the form_key in it, that means you have a module that overrides the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` block and thus, you need to modify this module so the `getDeleteUrl` function adds the form key to the URL.

If your delete URL does contain the form key, then you probably have a caching system that caches that specific block and thus provides the wrong form key.

Comment: I found delete link. It looks like this: /checkout/cart/delete/id/555/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5zaGF2aW5nc3f7fd77fd7e32Vzc29yaWVzLw/?___SID=U.  I noticed the form key is added after page refresh. Once I add a product I get the url I posted. After page refresh Form-key is added to the URL and product deletes.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
Not the right wray to do, please see @DigitalPianism answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/98957/33619

---

If I am not wrong you have to add a hidden input to your form :

```
<input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />
```

To find the right `.phtml` file you can use Magento template path hints.
Here you can find how to do it : http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you be more precise in what is not working ? Does it not working even if the `input` is added ?

Comment: I've added the code to template/checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml., thats my AJAX. No change, same error pops up when I try to delete a product.

Comment: When you debug your AJAX request did you see the param `form_key` sent  ?

Comment: I didn't debug, how to do that?

Comment: In this particular case, that is not the proper fix.

Comment: @DigitalPianism OK good to know thank you for the update ;)